# Exclude column header (but keep first) from a Table component on CSV export in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-csv

I know how to exclude column header from a *JR* report on *CSV* report.

I need to know how to exclude column header (but keep first) from a **Table component** on *CSV* report.

If this is not possible, any suggestion other than **ignore pagination** is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to add a **key** to each of the column Header report Element. (In this case, key="col_header" in the reportElement tag.)

```
<jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="50" rowSpan="1">
    <staticText>
        <reportElement uuid="0c6dfd58-9df2-4e00-b79e-43a457c7b42e" key="col_header" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="50"/>
             <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
              <font size="12"/>
         </textElement>
             <text><![CDATA[ColumnName]]></text>
    </staticText>
</jr:columnHeader>
```

Next, exclude the key when exporting to CSV. (Add this property to the report properties list).

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.key.col_header"/>
```

Voila, the column headers are removed in CSV export.

The downside of this approach:

- It removes all the column Headers. (net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.key.**keep.first**.col_header does not work).
- Adding Key to each column Header is quite laborious.

Answer (score 3):

By using this property you can keep your first header in your csv export.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.3=columnHeader
net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.report.3=*
```

You can use any another name if you already using 3 in your jrxml.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, just move all column headers to the title band and remove the column headers band itself, and it will only print once in your exported CSV.